# Android: Accessing Contacts from SIM card memory

Tags: android, mobile, contacts, sim-card

I've been tryin to develop an app which requires to access contacts from SIM memory. Here is the code i've used but there is runtime exception.

```
{  
    Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
    c=getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c);        
    getContacts();
}

private void getContacts(){
    int i=0;
    do {
        // Get the field values
        names[i++] = c.getString(0);        
    } while (c.moveToNext());
```

Any  answers and solutions are appreciated. Along with that could you please tell me the exact URI to access sim card contacts?? And is there any name for colums in the sim's contacts memory table?

Comment: could you add the exception that you get?

Comment: exception is something like "source could not be found" and the exception is exactly at 

c=getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null, null, null);

is that sim uri correct, is that same for all mobile phones..??

Answer (score 0):

Your content uri for sim contacts looks right.
I am using the following method to get contact details-

```
private void allSIMContact() {
    try {
        String m_simPhonename = null;
        String m_simphoneNo = null;
        String m_id = null;

        Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,
                null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        Log.i("PhoneContact", "total: " + cursorSim.getCount());

        while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {
            m_id = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            m_simPhonename = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim
                    .getColumnIndex("name"));
            m_simphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim
                    .getColumnIndex("number"));

            m_simphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D", "");
            m_simphoneNo.replaceAll("&", "");
            m_simPhonename = m_simPhonename.replace("|", "");

            ListData contact= new ListData(Integer.parseInt(m_id),
                    m_simphoneNo, m_simPhonename, "", "", "", false);
            arrayList.add(contact);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: "content://icc/adn" is for the android version over 1.6, for 1.5 "content://sim/adn".
Also insure the permission-
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>